# Using the Google Firebase app deployment with Aurelia how do you setup and deploy just the packed assets?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, minify

Currently I am trying to setup a successful configuration with [Aurelia](https://aurelia.io/) and [Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/).  The intent is to deploy just the compiled assets as a Google Firebase app.

I am a newbie with these new web frameworks since I am recently entering the world of compiled NodeJS apps and was wondering how these frameworks can coexist nicely and be deployed with the minified HTML, CSS, and JS.

Also, I have been using the Aurelia CLI up to now according to their documentation examples, but I don't know if this will work for Firebase deploys.

And Lastly, do I need to keep the Aurelia and Firebase directories separate, or can I just install aurelia-cli and the firebase-tools in the same app space safely?

Comment: You'll want to set the `public` key of your `hosting` config in `firebase.json` to point to the directory Aurelia CLI builds the compiled app into.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh You are right, but I found there is another way.  You can also set the  `platform.output` property to the firebase public path in `aurelia_project/aurelia.json`.  Which is better I don't know, but it gets the same results.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh if you can answer the question with these two options then I would accept it.  I would prefer that than to answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to deploy the compiled assets, which means either:

1. Changing the `platform.output` property to match the `public` path in the `hosting` config of `firebase.json`, or
2. Do the reverse and change the `public` directory in `firebase.json` to match the existing output path (likely `dist`)